# What event.target will contain if I added submit event listener on the form

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a lot of forms on the page and when one of them is submitted I want to send request via ajax to the view and have an id of the article and other info. So I need to check if form that has been clicked is the same as event.target. I did something like this but don't know if it is correct(first console.log works but second not):

```
<div id = "list">
            {% for article in news %}
                <a href="{{ article.resource }}"><h1>{{ article.title }}</h1></a>
                <p>{{ article.published }}</p>
                <img src = "{{ article.url }}">
                <p>
                    <button><a href="#" class="vote" id="{{ article.id }}" action = "upvote">Upvote</a></button>
                    <button><a href="#" class="vote" id="{{ article.id }}" action = "downvote">Downvote</a></button>
                </p>
                <div id="span">
                    {% with article.upvotes.count as total_upvotes and article.downvotes.count as total_downvotes %}
                        <span upvote-id = "{{ article.id }}">{{ total_upvotes }}</span><span> upvote{{ total_votes|pluralize}}</span>
                        <span downvote-id = "{{ article.id }}">{{ total_downvotes }}</span><span> downvote{{ total_votes|pluralize}}</span>
                    {% endwith %}
                </div>
                <form method = 'post' action = '{% url "news:news_list" %}' form-id = '{{ article.id }}' class="form">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type = "submit" value = "post">
                </form> 
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block domready %}
        const 
            list = document.getElementById('list'),
            items = document.getElementsByClassName('vote');
            forms = document.getElementsByClassName('form');

        list.addEventListener('click', voteFunc);
        list.addEventListener('submit', commentFunc);

        function commentFunc(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            const clickedForm = event.target;
            console.log('event triggered');
            for (let form in forms){
                if (form == clickedForm){
                    console.log('form is event.target')
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{% url "news:news_list" %}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {'id':$(event.target).attr('form-id'), 'title':$(this).elemets['title_field'].text(), 'body':$(this).elemets['body_field'].text()}, 
                        dataType: 'json'
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope to hear advice how to implement it better and what event.target contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write event handler for form submit event .So, whenever submit button(post) is clicked this event will get called then use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to get all inputs inside your form and also attach form-id using `&name=value` and then you can pass same to backend.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//when form will get submit
$("form.form").submit(function(e) {
  //serialize will get all inputs as name=value separted wth `& `
  console.log("data to send --> " + $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + $(this).attr('form-id'))
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{% url "news:news_list" %}',
    data: $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + $(this).attr('form-id'), //send same
    dataType: 'json'
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

  <a href="{{ article.resource }}">
    <h1>A1</h1>
  </a>
  <p>abcd..</p>
  <img src="{{ article.url }}">
  <p>
    <button><a href="#" class="vote" data-id="1" action = "upvote">Upvote</a></button>
    <button><a href="#" class="vote" data-id="1" action = "downvote">Downvote</a></button>
  </p>
  <div id="span">

    <span upvote-id="1">23</span><span> 54</span>
    <span downvote-id="1">2</span><span> 56</span>
  </div>
  <form method='post' action='{% url "news:news_list" %}' form-id='1' class="form">
    <p><label>somehting:</label>
      <input type="text" name="something"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="post">
  </form>

  <a href="{{ article.resource }}">
    <h1>A</h1>
  </a>
  <p>abcd..</p>
  <img src="{{ article.url }}">
  <p>
    <button><a href="#" class="vote" data-id="2" action = "upvote">Upvote</a></button>
    <button><a href="#" class="vote" data-id="2" action = "downvote">Downvote</a></button>
  </p>
  <div id="span">

    <span upvote-id="2">23</span><span> 54</span>
    <span downvote-id="2">2</span><span> 56</span>
  </div>
  <form method='post' action='{% url "news:news_list" %}' form-id='2' class="form">
    <p><label>somehting:</label>
      <input type="text" name="something"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="post">
  </form>
</div>
```